# working (compiling and running) on project with java 6 when java 8 installed

Tags: java, eclipse

I have java8 JDK installed on my computer. I work on my all projects with java 8, but now I need to develop another project, but with java 6! I'm using eclipse and when i do right click on a project, select properties -> java compiler -> compiler compliance level, there is possibility to switch between versions from 1.3 to 1.8. It looks like it was enough to develop project with whatever java version (lower or equal then I have installed), but I'm rather asking because I was searching and found many discussions on this topic, and all of them were difficult and I still have java 8 version on my classpath. Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have installed java8 jdk, and I have it on my classpath...I'm developing with java8, but I need to develeop one project with java6, and if it is the right way to do that.

Comment: You can target previous versions of the JVM. I don't see why you can't just install 1.6, though, if you're this concerned about it.

Comment: I can install java6, but then I have to switch my classpath between 1.6 and 1.8? or what

Comment: @CharlieHarper  I am sure Java 8 can understand Java 6. Some classes and functions are deprecated but they are not removed for back ward compatibility

Comment: @KickButtowski my problem is that I need it for a school project, the project will be automatically build, compile and run with java6 on server, and then I will see my score, I'm afraid it doesn't have to be allright with java8

Comment: ... If you target 1.6 you can't use 1.8 features. One of Java's strongest (weakest) features is backwards compatibility, that's one of the points of Java. Couldn't you even just *try* it?!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your question is: "I have Java 8 installed in eclipse, how do I start a new Java 6 project?"

Comment: @DoubleDouble yes you're right

Answer (score 1):

In your project Properties, select the **Java Build Path** section, then the **Libraries** tab.

[image]

There, select the **JRE System Library** and use the **Edit...** button. Select *Execution Environment" and choose `JavaSE-1.6`.

[image]

Once you've done that, it's a good idea to go back to the **Java Compiler** section and select the option *Use compliance from execution environment...*.

[image]

That will keep the compliance level in line with whatever Execution Environment is selected for the project.